# website performance: from cookies to local storage

Tags: php, local-storage

I created a plugin for a Wordpress website. Based on whether a user visited an (important) subpage, the plugin presents personalized information in the header of the website - on every page and pageload.

In the past I used a cookie that stored this information. But I learned this particular usage of cookies prevent caching and thus reduces my website performance

Now I am trying to implement the same functionality with local storage.

Question: Will the use of localstorage and presenting user specific information on the website via jQuery also slow down my website? Or will I see better performance of the website?

Comment: if its dynamic per user, caching is not an option.

Comment: How long do you store that they've been to a specific page? Is this per session, only ever time they login? Once per user?

Comment: When I used the cookie, I stored the data for 30 days. But if it's less, that would be okay. If the data expires after every window close, that wouldn't be the best situation

Comment: remember that not like cookies, data stored at local storage will not be sent to your server with every request

Comment: You will see very huges benefits, and is much easier to handle: `localStorage.setItem('entry', 'value')` `localStorage.getItem('entry')` straightforward! ;) You can store many Gb like this. Need 10% empty hard drive to develop, or your browser may completly skip it without warning. Best to know it!

Comment: So cache for 30 days? Or if you need persistence after browser close, when user logs out throw cache into a cookie or DB, then get it back when they login. It's really hard to advise the best approach without knowing what and why you need to do this :)

Comment: You aren't really changing the performance by using localStorage. What you are changing that matters is how you are *gettting* the user-info, not how you *store* it. By having the user-data retrieved by an ajax call, independent of the main page, you are improving a few things : 1) you aren't sending the data (via cookies) on every page request. 2) you are allowing those documents to be cached (and the user data request to be cached), 3) you are making dedicated requests for what you need, so you aren't making redundant requests to achieve multiple things.

Comment: Cookies has nothing to do with browser cashing the responses, it is all about [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)

Comment: @James - localStorage persists after the browser closes. Are you thinking of sessionStorage?

Comment: @Anthony I was talking about what the OP wants "*remains after browser close*" cache can be cleared at any time, mine when I close the browser. So "persistence" has to be away from user control - DB

Comment: @james To explain a little better: When a user visits an important subpage of the website, a menu item should be visible. If the user didn't visit the subpage, I basically want to hide this menu item. This can easily be achieved with localStorage and jQuery. This functionality is not super critical, but it enhances the user experiences. So when a user has his browser configured to clear cache/cookies with every window close, it's not critical

Comment: In which case you could just go with localStorage, benefits in Anthony's comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49888884/website-performance-from-cookies-to-local-storage?noredirect=1#comment86794157_49888884

Comment: You said "*When a user visits an important subpage of the website, a menu item should be visible. If the user didn't visit the subpage, I basically want to hide this menu item*" this sounds more like a job for a 2nd menu code and `if` statement. But you also stated in your question: "*personalized information*" This sounds like it should be stored permanently for each user, and so not sure the reason you'd allow this to be "reset" based on their clearing cache? If I have that right, then imo, store their personalized setting in the DB, and when login add it to their session or cache

Comment: @James your first statement is correct: "this sounds more like a job for a 2nd menu code and if statement". What do you mean by 2nd menu code?

Comment: That statement in your comment doesn't sounds like persistent specific to a user, just: when viewing a specific page don't show a sub menu. As said in my last comment, if this is not true then why not permanently store each users settings?

Answer (score 0):

The data can be stored at the client side if you don't need it on the server and there are no sensitive information. It will reduce the request and response size and therefore reduce server load and response times. It won't affect caching, since your wordpress page is dynamic anyways and probably won't cache at all without caching plugins.

Comment: I want to make use of caching. There are multiple static pages that can be cached, including the home - which is really important to be cached. With the PHP code checking if the cookie value is present, I think I prevent even static pages from being cached

Comment: Caching has to be used wisely. If you change the content on any of your cached dynamic pages, it will not reach all users immediately. Personalised information will eventually change, so caching pages displaying these information is not desirable. What is your reason for this type of caching?

Comment: To explain a little better: When a user visits an important subpage of the website, a menu item should be visible. If the user didn't visit the subpage, I basically want to hide this menu item. This can easily be achieved with localStorage and jQuery. So, of course I would like the server to cache the website, but I am not so sure if this jQuery / localStorage usage will prevent proper caching

Comment: If you would like to cache the page anyways then no, your "jQuery local storage" solution will not prevent caching. But it makes no sense, because you can render the data on the server without using the local storage or cookies to store it, since it will be cached anyways - with or without the data printed.
// EDIT: my bad, it makes sense in case you want to show the menu only once. But you should ask yourself - is it a good design and how does it help?